# Unable to scroll vertically in viewpager

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, scrollview

For several days I've been trying to implement a TabLayout with a ViewPager using Fragments. While showing the fragment and swiping between the tab works, i'm not able to scroll vertically in the fragment currently shown in the ViewPager.

I've found some solutions on SO that suggest implementing (Nested)ScrollViews in either the fragment or the activity layout in order to make the content scroll. I've tried several of approaches (while none of them work) - I conclude that I did something wrong and by now, I'm unable to figure it out.

I'm using the following code in order to achieve the current results:

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/caj_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/door_img [exists, not pasted]"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/door_img"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Test">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Setting up tab layout:

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.caj_tab_layout);
final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

pager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

I'm expecting to be able to scroll within the fragment, however, this is not possible. 
Did I miss an xml-tag?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, Could you solve it?